# how do I translate English Into bangla words correctly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some English words that i want to translate into bangala language. As i am using

```
`'from translate import Translator'`
```

this library and my output is like this - [image]

code is as follows

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(resource+"/input.xlsx")
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
   row_input = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
   detect_language = TextBlob(row_input)
   print(row_input , "is",  detect_language.detect_language())
   save=translator.translate(row_input)
   print(save)
```

Comment: Please do not take images of code or console outputs. Paste them directly into the post with the proper formatting applied.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -2):

Google provides Translator API using which you can convert text to any many languages.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/